# Laravel 5.1 service container: Binding using something other than the class name?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Bit of a long winded question, but here goes. I'm a little confused regarding some of the documentation for the service container in Laravel 5.1. I'll explain my current understanding of the container first, and then explain where my confusion has arisen.

So, I'm fairly sure I understand the process of registering a binding with the service container. To quote the documentation, you register a binding using the bind method, passing the **class or interface name** that we wish to register along with a Closure that returns an instance of the class:

```php
$this->app->bind('HelpSpot\API', function ($app) {
    return new HelpSpot\API($app['HttpClient']);
});
```

Now, in the Laravel 5.0 docs, that's actually stated slightly differently:

> A Closure resolver is registered in the container with a key (typically the class name) and a Closure that returns some value.

So, in Laravel 5.0, it seems you were able to bind some class, say `FooBar` to a key that, while recommended to be the class name, could be something different, so for example:

```php
$this->app->bind('myfoobarclass', function($app) {
    return new FooBar($app['SomethingElse']);
});
```

And then later you could resolve the class using:

```php
$fooBar = $this->app->make('myfoobarclass');
```

However, this would remove your ability ro resolve that class using type hinting, which I'm guessing is why the docs for 5.1 states specifically to use the class name. However, in the section on Facades (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/facades#facade-class-reference), they list the facades along with their "service container binding key", which is different to their class name. Does this mean you can't resolve these facades using type hinting? Why would they register their bindings as something other than their class name? Or is this documentation simply out of date?

If anyone could shed some light on the reasons behind this inconsistency that would be amazing, thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't normally resolve facades using type hinting, you type hint its underlying class (from the class reference you linked). This also gives you a minuscule performance increase when using the type hinted object, since Laravel doesn't have to resolve the facade.

Comment: @Ben Hey thanks for the comment, I actually have a vaguely related question regarding facades. On that documentation page (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/facades) they show an example using the Cache facade. At the top they import the Cache class using `use Cache;` but how is this class resolved? I can't find it in the autoloader classmap, yet I tried it and it doesn't cause an error so it must work?

Comment: It's a facade; they're in the global namespace, thus `use Cache`. All of the facades are listed in `config/app.php`

Comment: Re-posted this as an answer in case that's all you needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You normally bind implementations to interfaces. So instead of adding something to the service container by the name of the class, you would instead use the name of an interface it implements instead:

```
$this->app->bind('App\HttpClientInterface', function ($app) {
    return new \Guzzle\HttpClient;
});
```

You can then type-hint the `HttpClientInterface` interface in your application, and instead get the bound `GuzzleHttpClient` instance. This allows you to swap your implementations out in one place without having to re-write your application code.

You’re not restricted to using fully-qualified class/interface names, you can use arbitrary strings as key names if you wish:

```
$this->app->bind('http.client', function () {
    return new \Guzzle\HttpClient;
});
```

But you can’t type-hint on these; this is where you would use the `app()->make('http.client')` method instead.

In regards to the [Façade Class Reference](http://laravel.com/docs/master/facades#facade-class-reference) section of the Laravel documentation, there are two ways of resolving the services in your app.

1. You can type-hint on the value in the **Class** column, i.e. `Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher`
2. Alternatively, you can use what’s in the **Service Container Binding** column with the `app()->make('hash')` method. These are just “aliases” for the class name.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice answer! I've deleted mine as this is more thorough.

Comment: Thanks! this is great. Just to clear up one point, even though the docs removed the reference to binding to arbitrary strings in 5.1, you can actually still do this? Is there any reason you would?

Comment: @LeonAves You can, with the `$this->app->alias()` (which I imagine is what Laravel does under the hood). It’s a matter of preference I think, I personally use interface names as I don’t really like having magic `app()->make()`s in my code.